# Running java class from terminal

Tags: java, terminal

This question has been asked before but I still cannot figure whats wrong for some reason.
I got a class named NewClass in package syntaxtest in file src. From src path I type :

javac src/syntaxtest/NewClass.java

and the class is compiled and I can see NewClass.class in syntaxtest folder. Now from that same path or even the same folder with NewClass.class, I can't figure out how to run the class from terminal. I have made many different attempts but ether I get

ClassDefNotFound or ClassDefNotFound (wrong name : syntaxtest/NewClass)

Comment: did you try "java NewClass" ? make sure you're in its directory before trying the command(to have it in that form)

Comment: When I try java NewClass while I'm in the folder the NewClass.class is i get ClassDefNotFound. If i try java syntaxtest.NewClass I get ClassDefNotFound (wrong name: syntaxtest/NewClass) . When I try that name I get NoClassDefFound...

Comment: "java -cp . NewClass" try this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try "`java -cp src syntaxtest.NewClass`".

That is, if you have a folder "src" which contains the subfolder (package) "syntaxtest" and the class "NewClass" is in "package syntaxtest", then the above command will work.

```
$ ls src/syntaxtest
NewClass.java
$ cat src/syntaxtest/NewClass.java
package syntaxtest;
public class NewClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
$ javac src/syntaxtest/NewClass.java
$ java -cp src syntaxtest.NewClass
Hello, World!
```

Comment: nope doesn't work. tried few variations with slashes here and there but still nothing..

Comment: @latusaki: I'm assuming your package name is "syntaxtest"; if it is instead "src.syntaxtest" then try "`java src.syntaxtest.NewClass`".

Comment: no src is just a folder. Inside it has another folder named syntaxtest. then is the .java and .class file. NewClass is in syntaxtest package. Its quite strange I can't figure out how to call the class. Btw if i remove the package from class so its not in any package I can call it. So there must be something wrong with package.

Answer (score 2):

I've made the following test:

- Created a java file in home/test/blah/TestClass.java

  package blah;

  public class TestClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello World!");
      }
  }
- Went to directory home/test/
- Compiled the file by typing:

> ```
> javac blah/TestClass.java
> ```

- Got the file compiled ok.
- Ran it by typing:

> ```
> java blah.TestClass
> ```

- Got the message "Hello World!" as expected: program runs ok.
- Went to directory home/
- Tried to run by typing:

> java test/blah.TestClass

- ... and many other combinations of slashes and dots..... nothing worked.... keep getting the same Exception as you:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
> ```

So it seems to me that to run a Java class using the command 'java' you really must be in the application's root folder.

Comment: Nearly 10 years later: to run from another directory, use the `-cp` option to tell java what the "rootDir" is (where classes can be found)! The other answer shows that now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I wanted to organize my project using a src and bin folders directly from the Mac finder and use Emacs or some other text editor. I just didn't like eclipse.

You can't execute the classes from another folder, but you can do is compile from another folder into the one you are going to execute.

For example (assuming there is no package), move to the bin folder and run:

$ javac ../src/name.java -d ../bin/

(That compiles from the src folder and outs the .class file directly on bin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to package the class as a runnable JAR. This can be accomplished from your IDE. Then, just use the java -jar jarname.jar command to run your jar from the terminal without issues.

Comment: question is 11 years old and already has an accepted answer (also 11 years old) -- "You need to ..." should better be worded "You may ..."