# How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, jvm

I'm trying to execute a Java program from the command line in Windows.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {
            File afile = new File("input.txt");
            File bfile = new File("inputCopy.txt");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;

            // copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to execute the program - any help?
Is this possible on Windows?
Why is it different than another environment (I thought JVM was write once, run anywhere)?

Comment: `javac CopyFile.java` and then `java CopyFile`

Comment: I'm at the command line now, do I need to save my txt files in the same folder as the program for them to be invoked?

Comment: What package does `CopyFile` reside

Comment: @Elizabeth Turner first you have to make sure that you have installed JRE (Java Runtime Env) and that it's accessible form every folder (the path to Java/Javac is included in the PATH env variable). Then run the commands I wrote above from the same folder in which CopyFile.java is located.

Comment: See [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and this question [Running Java Program From Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9879679/16487).

Comment: @alfasin lets assume that JRE isn't installed, how would i go about installing it

Comment: @ARJUN, your link is no longer valid. It looks like it go to a spam place.

Comment: Check for JEP 330 for more information about running Java programs as if they was shell or Python scripts.

Comment: @elizabeth-turner, no you don't need to have the text file in the same place as the java program.  But you should probably use an argument to the `main` method to tell where it is, and then add to the command line the path to the file.  As for instance `dir`, `ls`, `copy` and `cp` works.

Comment: Check this link [Running a Java program from command Prompt](https://msccomputerscience4all.blogspot.com/2013/02/running-java-program-from-command-prompt.html)

Comment: As of Java 11 you can run directly from a single `.java` file. So `java CopyFile.java` should work.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Source: [javaindos.](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

> Let's say your file is in C:\mywork\
>
> Run Command Prompt
>
> ```
> C:\> cd \mywork
> ```
>
> This makes C:\mywork the current directory.
>
> ```
> C:\mywork> dir
> ```
>
> This displays the directory contents.  You should see
>   filenamehere.java among the files.
>
> ```
> C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin
> ```
>
> This tells the system where to find JDK programs.
>
> ```
> C:\mywork> javac filenamehere.java
> ```
>
> This runs javac.exe, the compiler.  You should see nothing but the
>   next system prompt...
>
> ```
> C:\mywork> dir
> ```
>
> javac has created the filenamehere.class file.  You should see
>   filenamehere.java and filenamehere.class among the files.
>
> ```
> C:\mywork> java filenamehere
> ```
>
> This runs the Java interpreter.  You should then see your program
>   output.
>
> If the system cannot find javac, check the set path command.  If javac
>   runs but you get errors, check your Java text.  If the program
>   compiles but you get an exception, check the spelling and
>   capitalization in the file name and the class name and the java
>   HelloWorld command.  Java is case-sensitive!

Comment: The issue im having is when i try to run the compiler I get an error "could not find or load main class CopyFile

Comment: If you have the folder containing CopyFile.class set as the current directory, simply try "java -cp . CopyFile" Otherwise "java -cp FULLPATH CopyFile"

Comment: How would I create a batch file that compiles&runs the code, yet if it was compile before, just launch it?

Comment: What's missing: if the class was declared to be in a certain package, then you have to put the `.class` file in the appropriate directory structure. Current directory is the default classpath, so you don't have to set `-cp .` manually.

Comment: For sure, you should be using a packages: package mypackage;     then go to your projectname/ .    Run java mypackage.Main

Comment: What happens when you run Java filenamehere. I'm guessing the java compiler DOESN'T compile anything and instead the .class file is being passed to the JVM?@NicholasKadaeux

Comment: @ElizabethTurner, I had the same error, and it was because I had opened the grandparent folder and I used a project with local packages at the start of the code. The result: I had multiple projects in the working directory. If you use **package [projectfoldername];** in the first lines of your code files, you must use **java [projectfoldername]\xyz.java** "outside the projectfolder", and with that folder structure of the package you also run the class afterwards. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234488/running-java-class-from-terminal

Comment: I was having a similar issue. As sugggested by @ArturCzajka I just needed to add -cp . but **it needs to be before the name of the class** So like this: java -cp . Test

Answer (score 119):

To complete the answer :

1. The Java File

   ```
   TheJavaFile.java
   ```
2. Compile the Java File to a *.class file

   ```
   javac TheJavaFile.java
   ```

   - This will create a `TheJavaFile.class` file
3. Execution of the Java File

   ```
   java TheJavaFile
   ```
4. Creation of an executable `*.jar` file

   - You've got two options here -

     1. With an external manifest file :

        - Create the manifest file say - MANIFEST.mf
        - The MANIFEST file is nothing but an explicit entry of the Main Class
        - `jar -cvfm TheJavaFile.jar MANIFEST.mf TheJavaFile.class`
     2. Executable by Entry Point:

        - `jar -cvfe TheJavaFile.jar <MainClass> TheJavaFile.class`
5. To run the Jar File

   ```
   java -jar TheJavaFile.jar
   ```

Comment: can you please show the contents of MANIFEST.mf, because when I try to "Executable by Entry Point" it says the main class can't be found

Comment: @Pini Cheyni If your class is called the MainClass then your manifest file will have an entry for the Main-Class : MainClass

Comment: @PiniCheyni, The 2 ways to create executable jars are explained well here.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: on point 3, when you call `java TheJavaFile` thats equivalent to `java TheJavaFile.class`.. so youre not executing the java file like you stated. youre executing the class file. java files are sources which are not executable

Answer (score 27):

Since Java 11, `java` command line tool has been able to run a single-file source-code directly. e.g.

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

This was an enhancement with JEP 330: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

For the details of the usage and the limitations, see the manual of your Java implementation such as one provided by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html

Answer (score 25):

**Complile** a Java file to generate a class:

```
javac filename.java
```

**Execute** the generated class:

```
java filename
```

Comment: Notice that  your "filename" is actually a name of a class. The java.exe will search every *.jar file for a class of this name.

Comment: @Doomjunky Could you explain it, please? Is that bad or good? Should it be named differently?

Answer (score 25):

In case your Java class is in some package. Suppose your Java class named `ABC.java` is present in `com.hello.programs`, then you need to run it with the package name.

Compile it in the usual way:

```
C:\SimpleJavaProject\src\com\hello\programs > javac ABC.java
```

But to run it, you need to give the package name and then your java class name:

```
C:\SimpleJavaProject\src > java com.hello.programs.ABC
```

Comment: works for java 8

Answer (score 12):

Assuming the file is called "CopyFile.java", do the following:

```
javac CopyFile.java
java -cp . CopyFile
```

The first line compiles the source code into executable byte code. The second line executes it, first adding the current directory to the class path (just in case).

Comment: mycomputer:bin user$ java -cp . Main.class 
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class

Answer (score 9):

It is easy. If you have saved your file as A.text first thing you should do is save it as A.java. Now it is a Java file.

Now you need to open cmd and set path to you A.java file before compile it. you can refer [this](http://www.elcaro-guide.com/java/how-to-compile-and-run-a-java-program) for that.

Then you can compile your file using command

> javac A.java

Then run it using

> java A

So that is how you compile and run a java program in cmd.
You can also go through these [material](http://www.elcaro-guide.com/java) that is Java in depth lessons. Lot of things you need to understand in Java is covered there for beginners.

Answer (score 8):

You can compile any java source using javac in command line ; eg, javac CopyFile.java.
To run : java CopyFile.
You can also compile all java files using javac *.java as long as they're in the same directory

If you're having an issue resulting with "could not find or load main class" you may not have
jre in your path. Have a look at this question:
[Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647448/could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7 I had to do the following:

**quick way**

1. Install JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
2. in windows, browse into "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin" (or wherever the latest version of JDK is installed), hold down shift and right click on a blank area within the window and do "open command window here" and this will give you a command line and access to all the BIN tools. "javac" is not by default in the windows system PATH environment variable.
3. Follow comments above about how to compile the file ("javac MyFile.java" then "java MyFile") https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149828/194872

**long way**

4. Install JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
5. After installing, in edits the Windows PATH environment variable and adds the following to the path C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath. Within this folder are symbolic links to a handful of java executables **but "javac" is NOT one of them** so when trying to run "javac" from Windows command line it throws an error.
6. I edited the path: Control Panel -> System -> Advanced tab -> "Environment Variables..." button -> scroll down to "Path", highlight and edit -> replaced the "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" with a direct path to the java BIN folder "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin".
7. This likely breaks when you upgrade your JDK installation but you have access to all the command line tools now.
8. Follow comments above about how to compile the file ("javac MyFile.java" then "java MyFile") https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149828/194872

Answer (score 3):

[image]
STEP 1: FIRST OPEN THE COMMAND PROMPT WHERE YOUR FILE IS LOCATED. (right click while pressing shift)
STEP 2: THEN USE THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS TO EXECUTE.
        (lets say the file and class name to be executed is named as Student.java)The example program is in the picture background.

```
     javac Student.java
     java Student
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9, the JDK includes `jshell`, a Java REPL.

Assuming the JDK 9+ `bin` directory is correctly added to your path, you will be able to simply:

1. Run `jshell File.java` — `File.java` being your file of course.
2. A prompt will open, allowing you to call the `main` method: `jshell> File.main(null)`.
3. To close the prompt and end the JVM session, use `/exit`

Full documentation for JShell can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/jshell/introduction-jshell.html).

Answer (score 2):

Now (with JDK 9 onwards), you can just use java  to get that executed.
In order to execute "Hello.java" containing the main, one can use: 
java Hello.java

You do not need to compile using separately using javac anymore.

Comment: This feature has been added in JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run Java program as you would shell or python scripts without manually compile the Java file, as described in
[JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330). That is available since JDK 11.

If you create a file `testing`, and put the following you should be able to run it as command `testing`.  You  need to make it executable in Linux and Mac OSX with `chmod +x testing`.

```java
    #!/usr/bin/env java --source 11
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

You are *not* allowed to use the file extension `.java` in the previous example.

```sh
    $ chmod +x testing
    $ ./testing
    Hello world!
    $
```

But you can still execute if it is was name `Test.java` without the shebang "#!" prefix like this:

```java
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String [] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello again!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Then execute the file `Test.java` with following command:

```sh
    $ java Test.java
    Hello again!
    $
```

So this works as long as you have a new enough Java compiler in the path, check with `java -version`.  More information in this [blog](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11).