# How to run NetBeans Java project from command line?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a NetBeans Java project which run fine on NetBeans. The application has several classes, reads from several files to take input and also uses Jackson jar library. Now, how to run this project from command line properly so that it gets required library and files it needs?

Comment: Do you use any build tool like ant,mave or gradle?

Comment: No. Should I? @erhun

Comment: Is it standalone application or web application or other??

Comment: It's just a simple Standalone Java Apllication. @VirajNalawade

Comment: if you are you can easily build, compile and run it. for maven just mvn clean build install command can be enough to prepare the final jar, then you can run the jar java -jar blabla.jar

Comment: I can have a jar of the application by building it on NetBeans. But somehow it throws exception. I have a code like 
'InputStream input = new FileInputStream("book-info-converter.properties");'
Does it create problems with jars? @erhun

Comment: *"Does it create problems with jars?"* - That depends, where is the `"book-info-converter.properties`" file stored in relationship to the program?

Comment: The file is in the root directory of the NetBeans project. Where should I put this file or any jar library that are required for the program? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Library/dependent Jar files will be place in the `lib` directory within the `dist` directory (assuming you're using Ant and not Maven).  The properties files should be placed in the same directory as the resulting jar file (ie the one in the `dist` directory).  You should copy the contents `dist` directory as a whole (you can rename the `dist` directory, but in order to run correctly, you will need to keep the contents in the same structure). You could modify the build process to copy the files you require into the `dist` directory, but that becomes another question

Comment: Use `java filename` as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137745/6532488)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans uses [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) for building. 
Install Ant then execute in terminal, under project folder:

```
ant run
```

[Tutorial on Ant for Netbeans](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ant.html)