# how to make input start on a new line in java

Tags: java, input, file-io

ok i want to make some kind of chat program to chat with the program but the problem is the cursor will not be in the right place only after i start typing it goes down , and some times it get stuck up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO6xC.png)
see how it got stuck like( sa af etc.) i tried making new line but it only pops after i input , and btw i use scanner to take input even readbuffer does the same thing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yarIu.png)

Comment: It's just a debugging console. It will probably be different if you start your program from the command line

Comment: @wvdz how can i start it from a console please tell me if you know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16137745/2947592