# Why do I keep getting an class not found exception

Tags: java, unix, classnotfoundexception

I tried running this on unix with javac & java command but it does not work

```
public class CommandLine {
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
  for( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
  System.out.println( args[ i ] );
  }
 }  
}
```

Comment: Do you have any package definition in this java file? if yes how are you using java command?

Comment: What is the detail error message. Does it say which class not found?

Comment: I always used and IDE to run my programs i'm not sure what you mean by defining a package

Comment: CommandLine.javaException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CommandLine/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CommandLine.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at

Comment: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: CommandLine.java. Program will exit.

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line) You might not be running from the correct directory

Answer (score 1):

When calling javac, list the `.java` file extension:

```
javac CommandLine.java
```

When calling java, do *not* list a file extension:

```
java CommandLine
```

The compiled class resides in the file `CommandLine.class`. So it would make sense for the command to run the program to be `java CommandLine.class`. However, `java` demands that the `.class` extension be dropped.