# Compiling multiple java classes with Notepad++

Tags: java, oop, notepad++

I compiled the following object oriented java implemetation of a Sokoban game with no errors with NetBeans IDE8.2

**My Player.java**

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    * and open the template in the editor.
    */
    package sokoban;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Player {

    //Standardkontruktor
    public Player() {

    }

    //Parametrisierter Konstruktor
    public Player(char[][] room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    //Attribut Raum
    private static char[][] room;

    private final static int X = 0;
    private final static int Y = 1;

    private final static char WALL = '#';
    private final static char PLAYER = '@';
    private final static char BOX = '$';
    private final static char GOAL = '.';
    private final static char PLAYER_ON_GOAL = '+';
    private final static char BOX_ON_GOAL = '*';
    private final static char FREE = ' ';

    private final static int[] UP = {0, -1};
    private final static int[] DOWN = {0, 1};
    private final static int[] LEFT = {-1, 0};
    private final static int[] RIGHT = {1, 0};

    //private static char[][] room;
     private static int freeBox;
     private static int emptyGoal;

      private static int[] size = {-1, 0};
    private static int[] player;

     /**
     * Function for vector addition
     *
     * @param first first vector
     * @param second second vector
     * @return new vector = first + second
     */
    private static int[] add(int[] first, int[] second) {
    return new int[]{first[X] + second[X], first[Y] + second[Y]};
    }

    //move Methode
    /**
     * Makes a move
     *
     * @param direction as a vector
     * @return true iff it was successful, otherwise false
     */
    public static boolean move(int[] direction) {
        int[] next = add(player, direction);

        switch (room[next[Y]][next[X]]) {
            case BOX_ON_GOAL:
            case BOX:
                int[] behind = add(next, direction);
                if (!(room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] == FREE || room[behind[Y]]    [behind[X]] == GOAL)) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (room[next[Y]][next[X]] == BOX_ON_GOAL) {
                emptyGoal++;
                freeBox++;
                }

                if (room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] == GOAL) {
                    room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] = BOX_ON_GOAL;
                    emptyGoal--;
                    freeBox--;
                } else {
                    room[behind[Y]][behind[X]] = BOX;
                }

               if (room[next[Y]][next[X]] == BOX_ON_GOAL) {
                    room[next[Y]][next[X]] = GOAL;
                } else {
                    room[next[Y]][next[X]] = FREE;
                }
            case GOAL:
            case FREE:
                if (room[player[Y]][player[X]] == PLAYER_ON_GOAL) {
                   room[player[Y]][player[X]] = GOAL;
                } else {
                    room[player[Y]][player[X]] = FREE;
                }

                player = next;

               if (room[player[Y]][player[X]] == FREE) {
                    room[player[Y]][player[X]] = PLAYER;
                } else {
                    room[player[Y]][player[X]] = PLAYER_ON_GOAL;
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
   }

    }
```

**My Level.java**

```
    package sokoban;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Level {

    //Standardkontruktor
    public Level() {

    }

    //Parametrisierter Konstruktor
    public Level(char[][] room) {
        this.room = room;
     }

    //Objekt Namens myPlayer vom Typ Player als Attribut eines Levels
    private final static int[] UP = {0, -1};
    private final static int[] DOWN = {0, 1};
    private final static int[] LEFT = {-1, 0};
     private final static int[] RIGHT = {1, 0};

     private final static int X = 0;
     private final static int Y = 1;

     private final static char WALL = '#';
     private final static char PLAYER = '@';
     private final static char BOX = '$';
    private final static char GOAL = '.';
    private final static char PLAYER_ON_GOAL = '+';
    private final static char BOX_ON_GOAL = '*';
    private final static char FREE = ' ';

    private static int freeBox;
    private static int emptyGoal;

    private static int[] size = {-1, 0};
    private static int[] player;

    Player myPlayer = new Player(this.room);

    //Attribut Raum
    private static char[][] room;

     public boolean isValidLevel(String file) {
        return this.loadLevel(file);
     }

     //Methode LoadLevel
    /**
      * Loads the level from the "file" and validate it
      *
      * @param file path to the file
     * @return false iff an error occurs or the level is invalid, true otherwise
     */
    private static boolean loadLevel(String file) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        try {
            bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file));
            bufferedReader.mark(100 * 100);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                size[Y]++;
                if (size[X] > -1 && size[X] != line.length()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    size[X] = line.length();
                }
            }

            bufferedReader.reset();
            room = new char[size[Y]][];

            int i = 0;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                room[i] = new char[line.length()];
                for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
                    room[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
                }
                i++;
                // oder room[i++] = line.toCharArray();
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < room[i].length; j++) {
                switch (room[i][j]) {
                    case FREE:
                    case BOX_ON_GOAL:
                    case WALL:
                        break;
                     case PLAYER_ON_GOAL:
                         emptyGoal++;
                    case PLAYER:
                        if (player != null) {
                            return false;
                         } else {
                            player = new int[]{j, i};
                        }
                       break;
                    case BOX:
                        freeBox++;
                        break;
                    case GOAL:
                        emptyGoal++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return !(player == null || emptyGoal != freeBox);
    }

    //Methode toString für die Ausgabe des Spielfeldes
    /**
     * Prints the level to the output stream
     */
    public String toString() {
    String safwensTempString = "";
    for (char[] row : room) {
            safwensTempString = safwensTempString + row;
        }
        return safwensTempString;
    }

    /**
     * Game logic for Sokoban
     *
     * @return true if the level was solved, otherwise false
     */
     public boolean isCompleted() {
         // create new Scanner that reads from console
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // flag if we quit the program
        boolean run = true;
        int[] direction;
        do {
            System.out.println(toString());
            System.out.println("Do you want to go up, down, left, right or exit the program?");

            // check which command was chosen and execute it
            switch (input.next()) {
                case "w":
                case "up":
                    direction = UP;
                    break;
                case "s":
                case "down":
                    direction = DOWN;
                    break;
                case "a":
                case "left":
                    direction = LEFT;
                    break;
                case "d":
                case "right":
                    direction = RIGHT;
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    run = false;
                    continue;
                default: // if the user input is not one of our commands print help
                    System.out.println("Command unknown! Please type up, down, left or right to move or exit to quit this program");
                    continue;
            }

            if (!myPlayer.move(direction)) {
                System.out.println("You can not go there!");
            }
        } while (run && emptyGoal != 0 && freeBox != 0);
        return run;
    }

    }
```

**My Sokoban.java**

```
    package sokoban;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
    * This class is the second part for the Sokoban game
    *
    */
    public class Sokoban {

    private static Level myLevel = new Level();

    /**
     * The Main method for the Sokoban game with contains all of the game logic
     *
     * @param args args[0] the path to the level
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String file = "sokoban.txt";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            file = args[0];
        }
       if (!myLevel.isValidLevel(file)) {
            System.err.println("Level has an invalid format");
            return;
        }
        if (myLevel.isCompleted()) {
            System.out.println("Yeah you have solved the level :)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have not solved the level :(");
        }
        System.out.println(myLevel.toString());
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
    }
```

**My Sokoban.txt (The map of the game)**

```
     #######
     #.@ # #
     #$* $ #
     #   $ #
     # ..  #
     #  *  #
     #######
```

Can anyone tell me how to compile this game with Notepad++?

I tried to compile like this:

Step 1: F6

Step 2:

```
cd C:\Users\Noureddine\Desktop\Sokoban finale Version
java Sokoban
javac Sokoban.java
```

and got the following error:

> Process started >>> Fehler: Hauptklasse Sokoban konnte nicht gefunden
>   oder geladen werden <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1) javac
>   Sokoban.java

Remark: I tried to install the ViSimulator but the installation failed.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your answers and hints!

Comment: I guess the cd fails due to the spaces inside. Probably you need `cd "C:\Users\Noureddine\Desktop\Sokoban finale Version"` (with the qoutes).

Comment: No this is not the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Then the next step is to try it in cmd alone, outside of notepad++ and see what is needed until it works there, I mean setting of environment variables like `PATH` and `CLASSPATH`, etc..

Comment: BTW. is the order of commands correct? First java and then javac? I would have done it the other way around.

Comment: Also I think there is a naming clash between the directory `Sokoban finale Version` and the package name `sokoban`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For compiling your files you use:

```
javac Sokoban.java
```

Since you are using packages I think you have to give the full name to run your program:

```
java sokoban.Sokoban
```

Maybe take a look at this question: [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-to-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Indeed, it appears the only real issue was inverting `java` and `javac` during the compiling process.

Answer (score 0):

Open the directory where you have saved your java file. There you can open command line then type:

**step 1:** `javac filename.java`

**step 2:** `java filename`

make sure that filename is same as that of the class you have written in your java program.