# NoClassDefFoundError when running HelloWorld.class

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

[image]

Im getting this error when I try to run HelloWorld.class

From this it looks like it's trying to run HelloWorld/class. The program should simply print out HelloWorld!.

```
package threads;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is not the correct way to run java from command line. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows

Comment: I have done exactly that. Im first compiling the java-file with javac.exe then I'm running the class-file with java.exe. Im still getting this error..

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath: `Select Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables > CLASSPATH`.
You can make a new variable there OR in the command prompt type: `SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2(or whatever version you are using)\bin`.

Type: `cd C:\Users\David\Desktop\eclipse\JNP\bin\threads`
this is your DIRECTORY NOT your CLASSPATH

Type: `javac HelloWorld.java`
a class file named HelloWorld.CLASS should appear in the threads folder.
Type: `java HelloWorld`

Also make sure you have named the file `HelloWorld.java`

I hope this helped!