# How to compile and run Java code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, compilation, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code and installed the "[Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)" by Microsoft.

Afterwards I downloaded the jdk1.8.0_161 and created the required environment variables as described in the "Java Extension Pack" documentation.

I then created a new file with .java ending and wrote a simple "Hello World" test program.

But how can I now compile and run the code?

Comment: Read the documentation for VSCode and the Java pack?  BTW,t he link you gave for the Java pack is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step, try to compile your programm from te command line. E.g.
[How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows) is a good start. You can run the commands directly in VSCode's integrated terminal.
Optionally, create a VS Code build task from that command to run builds with the build command.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Foo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "javac foo.java",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

To run/debug, create a launch config in the debug viewlet, for example:

```
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-Foo",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "mainClass": "Foo",
            "args": ""
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Attach)",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What about if I have multiple files in my project?

Comment: What is `debug viewlet` for running the program, is it `settings.json` in `.vscode`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the overall steps:

- Install the Java Extension Pack --> you did this already
- Create a Java project: `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type "Java". Choose the option "Java: Create Java Project"
- Modify the App.java class and save it: `Ctrl + S`

When you save it, VS Code automatically compiles the java files for you. In the **bin/app** directory you'll see a file called "App.class". That's the confirmation you need.

**Edit**: Running the project:
To run the project, hit F5. VSCode will ask if you want to add a configuration. Choose "Java: Launch Program". Make sure you have App.java opened and hit F5 one more time. That's it.

I noticed that VSCode does not deal well with packages, but that is for another question.