# VS code not auto compiling java after saving changes

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have used Java with Vs Code before and after writing the code I had to compile it just once then all the chances made were auto compiled. But now, for some reasone I have to Compile it every time after I make a change in the code or it shows the previous result for whatever input I give.

Can someone tell me what went wrong here and how to fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439522/how-to-compile-and-run-java-code-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: It sounds like your Java-in-VsCode compilation is writing the .class files to a different place (directory) to your Java-from-the-command-line compilation.

Comment: but the .class file seems to be in the same folder.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

Please use [the official extension to execute the script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_running-and-debugging-your-program), which will not let you execute it every time you compile it.

[image]

Java extensions usually generate `.class` files in the `bin` directory, you can change this setting

```json
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
```