# Unable to run java with command line arguments

Tags: java

I have been trying to run Java with command line arguments, but for some reason the class can not be found. I am very certain the directory is correct. Is there any way to fix this?

CLDemo.java file

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("It works!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post the code as formatted text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `cd out\production` before `java CLDemo`.

The default compile output of IntelliJ IDEA is under `out\production` folder, and Java needs to run at the corresponding package (folder) of your compile output.