# How to run an eclipse project without eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't have eclipse installed. I have a Java project with an `eclipse` folder in it.

Can I simulate pressing the Run button in eclipse, without installing eclipse.

I want to run this project.

I am on macOS. It's a pretty huge project, I am not sure how to compile the source correctly. I also don't know what external dependencies this project has.

Comment: You need to compile the classes by yourself and launch the main class

Comment: If you just want to run the code verbatim, what's stopping you from compiling it and running it either through the command line or another IDE (like IntelliJ or NetBeans)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: if your project is based on maven or gradle you can run them by ./gradlew or ./mvn

Comment: @Makoto don't have another IDE. Don't know how to correctly compile it.

Comment: @Spara it's not based on either although I wish it was

Comment: "_I also don't know what external dependencies this project has._" - figuring that out is a key first step - you're not going to be able to compile without knowing all the dependencies.

Comment: @Krease how do I figure that out from the eclipse folder

Comment: An Eclipse project folder can be recognized by the `.project` file it contains. A Java project contains also the file `.classpath`. Your `eclipse` folder is not Eclipse-specific. Please let us know what is in the folder.

Comment: @howlger a `.classpath` file and a `.metadata` folder, and two folders each with `.project` files in their top-levels (as well as `.settings`, `.classpath`, and some other folders)

Comment: What is in the `.classpath` and `.project` files?

Answer (score 1):

Without an external build tool to help with building the application like Gradle or Maven, you're going to *have* to download a copy of Eclipse and run it from there.  You'll also need to take the time to ensure that you convert your project to either a Maven or Gradle-based project so that you can build it independent of what IDE you're using.