# Execute Java Swing GUI application from command-line

Tags: java, swing, command-line, jframe

I have Java files structure like:

```
Gadget.java
GadgetShop.java
Mobile.java
MP3Player.java
```

`GadgetShop.java` file contains main method

```
package thegadgetshop;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GadgetShop extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
....
```

I used this command to run the file:

```
javac GadgetShop.java
```

And I got these errors:

> GadgetShop.java:44: error: cannot find symbol 
> private ArrayList listGadgets;
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:332: error: cannot find symbol
> private Gadget getGadget(int displayNumber) {
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:265: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = new Mobile(model, size, dPrice, iWeight, iCredit);
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:265: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = new Mobile(model, size, dPrice, iWeight, iCredit);
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:297: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mp3Payer = new MP3Player(model, size, dPrice, iWeight, iMemory);
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:297: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mp3Payer = new MP3Player(model, size, dPrice, iWeight, iMemory);
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:333: error: cannot find symbol
> Gadget gadget = null;
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:363: error: cannot find symbol
> Gadget gadget = getGadget(iDisplayNumber);
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:375: error: cannot find symbol
> if (gadget instanceof Mobile) {
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:376: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = (Mobile) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:376: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = (Mobile) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:382: error: cannot find symbol
> if (gadget instanceof MP3Player) {
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:383: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mP3Player = (MP3Player) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:383: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mP3Player = (MP3Player) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:419: error: cannot find symbol
> Gadget gadget = getGadget(iDisplayNumber);
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:423: error: cannot find symbol
> if(gadget instanceof Mobile) {
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:425: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = (Mobile) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:425: error: cannot find symbol
> Mobile mobile = (Mobile) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class Mobile
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:466: error: cannot find symbol
> Gadget gadget = getGadget(iDisplayNumber);
> ^
> symbol:   class Gadget
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:470: error: cannot find symbol
> if(gadget instanceof MP3Player) {
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:472: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mP3Player = (MP3Player) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> GadgetShop.java:472: error: cannot find symbol
> MP3Player mP3Player = (MP3Player) gadget;
> ^
> symbol:   class MP3Player
> location: class GadgetShop
> Note: GadgetShop.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> 22 errors

I don't know why its not compiling and running from CMD while its running fine in Netbeans. I really need to run it from CMD.

I also used this command but got same error:

```
javac -Xlint GadgetShop.java
```

### Edit 1

I have this files structure in Netbeans:

[image]

And files and classes structure in folder directory:

[image]

Comment: Post your class(es). This looks like a simple case of a missed semi-colon or some illegal use of a modifier. You might also need to define the classpath for the application if you have dependencies for it.

Comment: try javac thegadgetshop.GadgetShop.java

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I've also tried it by following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html) . But not found helpful.

Comment: @Jason will you elaborate more your comment makes more sense.

Comment: Can you post the project on GitHub?

Comment: when you compile make sure you're in the folder when the java files are placed. also as jason said these can be actual error in the source

Comment: You probably need to compile Gadget.java first. You could also do something like "javac *.java"

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to navigate to the folder where your project is to run it.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows), I think it will answer your question.