# can not find symbol method printIn (string) location: variable out of type PrintStream -java compile error

Tags: java

```java
class Example {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.printIn("This is a simple Java program.") ;
   }
}
```

I tried to compile the code through Command prompt. The error message is as follows:

```
Example.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.printIn("This is a simple Java program.") ;
               ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

I am a very beginner in java. Please help to understand the error.

Answer (score 5):

You have written `printIn` rather than `println`. You have an uppercase `i` not a `l` (L). Thus the compiler cannot find the method, thus the error `cannot find symbol` occurs.

The `ln` in `println` is for *line*.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("This is a simple Java program.");
   }
}
```

You had the wrong method name `printIn` instead of `println`.

Comment: I have corrected the method as println. But no result in command prompt as follows:Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sanal>cd desktop

C:\Users\sanal\Desktop>javac Example.java

C:\Users\sanal\Desktop>

Comment: If you have Java <= 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows, for Java >8 https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/ Also, watch some decent video tutorial to have such issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

that is System.out.println yours not correct sentence so that its raised error