# How do I run a java program I wrote on Intellij OUTSIDE of Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner, and I have a question that many could consider dumb, but I really just created an account to understand this, since I have not find an answer anywhere else.

So, I start a few days ago and I created a simple test program in Intellij, where I make some questions and then the ''user'' answers it, and then I create phrases of it.

But I would like to run it like a normal program, with an icon, where I click it twice and it opens in a new window.
I already know hot to run it in Intellij. I want to run it as a program outside of it. Is it clear ?
Can someone enlighten me about how can I do this?

Comment: Your description is a little vague. The simplest way for anyone to provide answer for this question will be to see intellij's run configuration window. Otherwise, you can use java -jar Jarfile name. Configuration window will provide more details to answer the question like the build is using maven or gradle, what is the main class, is it a web app or standalone etc.

Comment: If you look in the top of the console tab (probably adjacent to the one you use to debug in) the first line will be what that IDE is using to start your program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: just try the method how described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file/147233#147233)