# AccountTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I'm currently learning java and i was trying out an example from my textbook but i can't get it to work. I keep getting the "cannot find symbol" error.
This is the code in class Account:

```
package account;

public class Account {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

And this is for AccountTest:

```
package account;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Account myAccount;
        myAccount = new Account();
        System.out.printf("initial name is %s%n%n", myAccount.getName());

        System.out.println("Please enter the name:");
        String theName = input.nextLine();
        myAccount.setName(theName);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("name in object myAccount is: %n%s%n", myAccount.getName());
    }
}
```

The error message i get is:

```
javac AccountTest.java
AccountTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            Account myAccount;
            ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class AccountTest
AccountTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            myAccount = new Account();
                            ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class AccountTest
2 errors
```

Sorry for the newbie question and thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Where do you get "can not find symbol" error? I'm able to run your code successfully

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Are you sure both classes are placed in a package and folder named `account`?

Comment: @DaanVanDeVelde can you ensure that you are using English characters in the code? Some times, it's possible to use the same letters from different keyboards, e.g. 'A' and 'А' looks the same, but in fact they are different (different alphabet and different language).

Comment: @ManishGiri They are in the same folder and package.

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov i have used the same keyboard settings for both classes.

Comment: How are you attempting to compile?

Comment: I'm trying to run it through command prompt (sorry if this is not what you meant, i'm just following my textbook). When i try to run it through my IDE it seems to work.

Comment: If you're using the command prompt, make sure you first `cd` to where the `account` folder is.

Comment: I have already done that, when i tried to do 
    javac Account.java
it didn't give me an error code

Comment: Try to import the `Account` class explicitly in your `AccountTest` class - `import account.Account;`. This would be required only for compilation via command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already done that, when i tried to do javac Account.java it didn't give me an error code.

You need to specify both classes when you compile from the command line.

```
javac -cp . account/*.java
```

And then

```
java -cp . account.AccountTest
```

to run it.

Comment: This is what i get: 
C:\Users\Daan\Documents\School\NetBeansProjects\Account\src\account>javac -cp . *.java

C:\Users\Daan\Documents\School\NetBeansProjects\Account\src\account>java -cp . Account.AccountTest
Error: Could not find or load main class Account.AccountTest

Comment: move up one folder to `src`. The class name includes the package name, and that maps to the folder structure. The [`javac` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) covers this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine. When you use IDE - it work normally. But when you complile it like this from console:

```
cd account <-- move to your package with Account and AccountTest classes
javac AccountTest.java
```

You about to reseive this problem. Reason is `javac` does not include all imported files or files in the current directory automatically (this IDE does). So all you have to do is to tell `javac` all files for compile.

```
javac AccountTest.java Account.java
```

As result you will see `AccountTest.class` and `Account.class` files in your folder.

**And finally** to run your code from console you should do:

```
java -classpath . AccountTest
```

***P.S.** Look at this relevant answer* [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: So now i don't have an error code, but when i try
    java AccountTest
i get
    error: could not find or load main class AccountTest

Comment: @DaanVanDeVelde `java -classpath . AccountTest`

Comment: @DaanVanDeVelde since the class AccountTest is in package account you have to do: `java -cp . account.AccountTest`, that is `java -classpath <path_to_.class_files> <package>.<class_name>`