# Java program runs on IDE but not on terminal

Tags: java, terminal, classnotfoundexception

I have a simple Java code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of the days");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int days = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The number of seconds in the entered days number is "+days*86400);
    }
}
```

The folder structure is: `src\com\company`

Inside folder `company`, there are `Main.java` and `Main.class` files.

When I run the app in IDE it runs, when I try to run it on the terminal, I get:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class**

The execution of commands in any of the following ways

- From inside `company` folder:

```
java Main.class
```

- From inside `src` folder:

```
java com.company.Main.class
java.com.company.Main
```

give the same error.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try ```java Main``` while in src folder. I think that is the command . Before running you need to compile using ```javac Main.java``` .

Answer (score 0):

Complile a Java file to generate a class:

> javac filename.java

Execute the generated class:

> java filename

Example

> javac Main.java

> java Main

Detailed answer can be found here [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)