# Java Compiler on Windows wont create executable, only .class

Tags: java, windows

**Disclaimer**: The question has a similar solution and arguably duplicated from ["How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows), but I still believe it can be helpful to those whom asked the same wrong questions like me.

My mistake, as it can be found in the comments, was to be expecting the compiler to spill out an extensionless executable file (like in C), but instead, I only saw a .class file being created, leading me to run mistakenly `java filename.class`

If that happens, just run `java filename` with no extension and the code will run correctly.

---

I'm a very beginner at java and don't have the option of using it in Linux, so I was following the tutorial from an algorithm course on [Coursera from Princeton Uni](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/home/welcome), and I installed the jdk-11.0.2 from here: https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/

Just to see myself getting a class file instead of an executable after running `javac file.java`

I searched around and couldn't find anything so far, so I hope someone here saw a similar issue at some point.

[image]

The code, just to avoid suspiciousness over it:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

NB: IntelliJ on Windows compiles and runs it perfectly through the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:{PATH_TO_INTELLIJ}\lib\idea_rt.jar=64104:{PATH_TO_INTELLIJ}\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath {PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT};{PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT}\.lift\stdlib.jar;{PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT}\.lift\introcs.jar HelloWorld
```

[image]

Comment: A java compiler produces compiled code (`.class`) files.  To run it, you invoke it w/o the extension (i.e. `java HelloWorld`)

Comment: No way... I was running `java HelloWorld.class` cause I didn't see any extensionless file haha.. running only `java HelloWorld` worked hahaha thanks

Comment: please add this as an answer and let me upvote and choose you as the answer guy haha

Comment: actually, it might be best to close this question as a duplicate... Feel free to delete the question if you feel like it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows

Comment: @blurfus do you think so? I didn't get to that post easily after some minutes of searching, might be helpful for someone that got to the wrong direction as me. But fair to include the reference in the main body. If more people agree with you upvoting your comment I will delete.

Comment: I think so but it's your question so I'd leave it up to you as to what to do with it :) - have a good day mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A java compiler produces compiled code (`.class`) files.

To run it, you invoke it w/o the extension (i.e. `java HelloWorld`)

More details: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/

Comment: need to wait 8 minutes to accept it.. thanks mate

Comment: cheers, glad I could help.