# Cannot run Java app on cmd using Java11 and Windows

Tags: java, windows, cmd, console-application, java-11

I ahve tried several approaches as on [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows) and create exactly the same class and packages to use the same things.

Here is the sample class located on `C:\SimpleJavaProject\src\com\hello\programs`:

```
package com.hello.programs;

public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Then I compile it in the usual way:

```
C:\SimpleJavaProject\src\com\hello\programs > javac ABC.java
```

Later, run it by giving the package name and then my java class name:

```
C:\SimpleJavaProject\src > java com.hello.programs.ABC
```

In each time I try to run java app, I get "*Error: Could not find or load main class com.hello.programs.ABC*" error. Then have a look at [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) page and tried some approaches on that page. But still the same error.

It is too simple, but still I have not managed to run the simple app yet. So, how to fix this problem? And after running the app, how can I pass args on cmd?

**Update:** I could already generate `ABC.class` file by running the following command. BUT, I cannot run the app and see the "Hello world" on the console.

```
cd C:\SimpleJavaProject\src\com\hello\programs
javac ABC.java
```

--> generates `ABC.class` in C:\SimpleJavaProject\src\com\hello\programs

Comment: Note that a program as simple as yours can be run as single-source file using just `java ABC.java` which will compile and run the program in one go.

Comment: @Holger  I am wondering if you just create a simple app and test your answer in your PC?

Comment: Why do you think I didn’t?

Comment: Because none of the suggestions are working and if there is not a missing poiğnts, you should not tried.

Answer (score 1):

> `java com.hello.programs.ABC`

When you run this, java is going to check each and every `CLASSPATH` path for that + `/com/hello/programs/ABC.class`, will load that, and then run it.

This must mean that either:

[A] Your classpath does not include the current directory; The fix is `java -cp . com.hello.programs.ABC`.

[B] you didn't do what you wrote, and e.g. `dir com/hello/programs.ABC.class` prints nothing.

Note that you're not doing it right; a class file should never be in a directory path that includes `src`. If you don't want to bother with build tools like maven or gradle, I strongly suggest you don't bother with a `src` dir then either. If you must, the `-d` option can be passed to `javac` to tell it where tou put the file. If you want to separate source and class files, then that should be targeting a directory named `bin` or `build` or whatnot (a sibling of the `src` dir).

Comment: So go to the directory you already show in this question (The `src` dir, __not__ `src/com/hello/programs`), and once you're there, run `java com.hello.programs.ABC`). If that doesn't work, run `java -cp . com.hello.programs.ABC`.

Comment: Your example is close to work, but you did not give the directories where I should run the commands. So, there are some unnecessary folders created. I am wondering if you just create a simple app and test your answer in your PC?

Comment: That's because the command is to be run in the exact directory your question already posited. Just do what you, yourself, said you did. Follow your own instructions. I have, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `javac ABC.java` you are compiling the class, and `javac` places it in the current directory.

So `java com.hello.programs.ABC` would not work (because `com/hello/programs/ABC.class` file does not exists).

You can use the javac `-d` flag:

```
-d <directory>               Specify where to place generated class files
```

For instance:

```sh
> javac -d . ABC.java
> java com.hello.programs.ABC
Hello world
> cd com\hello\programs
> dir
ABC.class
```

Would work, because `javac` did place ABC in com/hello/programs.

**Update**: For clarity, once you compiled using `javac -d . ABC.java` you can run it using `java com.hello.programs.ABC` and you should see `Hello world` in the screen.

Comment: Your example is close to work, but you did not give the directories where I should run the commands. So, there are some unnecessary folders created. I am wondering if you just create a simple app and test your answer in your PC?