# Nothing happens when I run javac on command prompt

Tags: java

On Command Prompt I see the following

```
C:\Users\lek-h\Downloads\OOP>javac Example.java

C:\Users\lek-h\Downloads\OOP>
```

*(i.e., no response from Command Prompt)*

**Java file**

Under the following C:\Users\lek-h\Downloads\OOP\Example.java I have

```
class Example {
    // A Java program begins with a call to main().
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Java drives the Web.");
    }
}
```

**I have jdk 17 installed and set as path in system.**

Under my system variables, I have
System variable `JAVA_HOME` with value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`
System variable `JAVA_PATH` with value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17`

Under user variables I have
Variable `Path` with one value being `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: That's exactly what you should see if your code compiles successfully. Congratulations! There should be a file `Example.class` in your current directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run two commands for running the java file.

1. javac <filename.java>
2. java   < filename >

Run these commands on your command prompt:-

```
1) javac Example.java
2) java Example
```

Run these commands and check the output.

Comment: Thanks for the response Harsh! I've tried the following and have not elicited any response. No Example.class was created, the println response was not shown in comand line either

`1a. javac Example.java`  
`1b. java Example.java`  

`2a. javac Example`  
`2b. java Example`

Comment: Try it once again. " javac filename.java" then type, " java filename". Or else check your path configuration.

Comment: `You need to run two commands for the java file compilation.` - that's not accurate. First command will do `compilation`, second will start JVM with given arguments

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second command will start the java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly run the program using the `java` command.

```
java Example.java
```

Comment: I think you didn't mean to include `.java` -> `java Example`

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken No, that was intentional. It is a feature first introduced in Java 11: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: Okay good, thanks @unmitigated

Comment: Thanks for the response Unmitigated! This comment ovelaps with mine to the above answer, but yeah `java Example.java` didn't work either